# Shiny mouse coordinates are in pixel

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I replicated [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html), which worked fine until I loaded the app on a server. On the server the mouse coordinates are captured based on the pixel position on the screen instead of being based on the unit of the plot.